# Glassfish and JodaTime

Tags: java, glassfish, jodatime

I am using `Glassfish 3.1.2.2` to host several web applications, some of which use `JodaTime`. Recently, I've updated the version of `JodaTime` from `1.6.2` to `2.0`. After doing this, I get problems with errors like this:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.joda.time.DateTime.compareTo(Lorg/joda/time/ReadableInstant;)I
```

Usually this indicates a dependency-crash on the classpath, but I couldn't find that my project had multiple versions of `JodaTime`, `2.0` was the only one. After some more digging, and debugging to find where the `DateTime`-class is loaded from, I found that it is loaded from `[glassfish]\modules\joda-time-1.6.2.jar`, which is of course not what I want.

Why does glassfish include a specific version of a library like `JodaTime` on the classpath of every application, and is it safe to remove it/replace it with version `2.0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GlassFish doesn't include any version of JodaTime.

I guess you placed the jar file in `[glassfish]\modules` by yourself and forget that you did that. You can have a look at a fresh GlassFish installation to validate that.

It is safe to delete the old version from the `modules` folder.